# Лучший способ "Убить" веб страницу?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, webbrowser

Цель - создать функцию, которая полностью убьет веб страницу кроссбраузерно. Пока искал, нашел несколько вариантов, но не уверен в них.

Лучший, конечно, `window.close();`. Но работает далеко не везде. Еще один классный вариант - `window.location = 'about:blank'`. Еще предложения?

Важно, чтобы после выполнения функции даже с помощью <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> нельзя было что-либо прочесть.

Comment: Как написано в ответе, циклом. Но зачем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой вариант

```js
while(true);
```

Comment: У меня браузер через некоторое время предложил остановить скрипт.

Comment: не нужно такой код в сниппет выносить :)